# shipping methods on magento 2.3.2 not showing correct

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, frontend-error

Please I need help,my shipping methods showing [image]

I need it to showing normal like
[image]

Comment: Please explain in brief how to want you??

Comment: you see on the 1st image agreat space from word shipping methods and price .i need to decrease it like second img

Comment: i fixed it thanx

Comment: Can you explain me how to fix??

Comment: I edit table design on  shipping-method and  shipping-list files